# Reverse the order of Counter() output

Tags: python, counter, reverse, tokenize

Does anyone know to reverse the order of .Counter() output without doing a new list comprehension?
I mean when using .Counter() on a list of 'tokenized' words from raw text, one will get, for example

```
[('a', 100),
 ('b', 90),
 ('c', 80),
 ('d', 50),
 ('e', 10)]
```

Is there an easy way to swap the order of elements in each of the .Counter() output tuples such that it becomes

```
[(100, 'a'),
 (90, 'b'),
 (80, 'c'),
 (50, 'd'),
 (10, 'e')]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Counters don't actually define an ordering for their items. How did you get that first list? Unless you did something to explicitly sort it, that order was a fluke.

Comment: Could you show what you've tried?

Comment: I simply used the default command Counter(token_list). I don't think Counter() generates its output format in way like a fluke.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm pretty sure he means the order in which the keys are mapped to the values. He wants to switch the keys and values around.

Comment: @ChristianDean: oh, huh, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Why avoid a list comprehension?

Comment: FYI: this is not the output from collections.Counter.
Counter produces a dictionary, not a list of tuples:
`Counter('abcdefghi')` returns 
`Counter({'a': 1,
         'b': 1,
         'c': 1,
         'd': 1,
         'e': 1,
         'f': 1,
         'g': 1,
         'h': 1,
         'i': 1})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension to reverse the order of the tuples:

```
>>> data = \
[('a', 100),
 ('b', 90),
 ('c', 80),
 ('d', 50),
 ('e', 10)]
>>> 
>>> pprint([(b, a) for a, b in data])
[(100, 'a'), (90, 'b'), (80, 'c'), (50, 'd'), (10, 'e')]
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, that's much easier.

Comment: @ChrisT. Thanks. But you do know this is a list comprehension? ;-) Is there a reason you didn't want to use them at first.

Comment: Just trying to find out if there are other ways to do it. If this thread is deemed as inappropriate, I can remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
>>> lst = [(100, 'a'),
           (90, 'b'),
           (80, 'c'),
           (50, 'd'),
           (10, 'e')]

>>> map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), lst)
[(100, 'a'), (90, 'b'), (80, 'c'), (50, 'd'), (10, 'e')]
```

Which avoids list comprehension.

Comment: Kudos to both of you. I think Christian's original answer was easier, but I was thinking if there exists some built-in commands in 'collections.Counter()' that will do the trick without having to invoke list comprehension (e.g., order=reverse).

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the dataset you offered...

```
>>>original = [('a', 100),
               ('b', 90),
               ('c', 80),
               ('d', 50),
               ('e', 10)]
```

While your questions seeks to solve this problem without using a new list comprehension, Python allows you to easily process one list and make a new list using list comprehensions AND using them is

- Pythonic (widely recognized as idiomatic and effective Python programming practice by the broader community)
- extremely fast, under the hood... list comprehensions have been heavily optimized for speed and efficiency

The example below creates a list composed of tuples where the order of elements in each of the tuples is swapped

```
>>> output = [(y, x) for x, y in original]

>>> print(output)
[(100, 'a'), 
 (90, 'b'),
 (80, 'c'), 
 (50, 'd'), 
 (10, 'e')]
```

Based on the OP's comments about whether Counter has a builtin mechanism to do this swapping...

`collections.Counter` comes with these methods, none of which do the job requested.

```
.clear()
.fromkeys()
.keys()
.popitem()
.update()
.copy()
.get()
.most_common() 
.setdefault() 
.values()
.elements()    
.items()
.pop()
.subtract()
```

Comment: @gobrewers14 While OP did say _"without doing a new list comprehension"_, he seems perfectly fine with using them. See my answer. Besides, my timings show that using a list comp would be nearly twice as fast as `map/lambda`. So the OP should probably consider using them anyway.

Comment: @gobrewers14 my revised answer addresses multiple nuances of the OP's question. = )